# Enabled nfs service fails to start

Tags: debian, systemd, nfs

I have attempted to install `nfs` on my Pi3 running Raspbian

I have installed:-

```
sudo apt-get install rpcbind nfs-kernel-server
```

Added to `/etc/exports`

```
/var/www    *(rw,fsid=0,sync)
/home   *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Run `sudo exportfs`

I have enabled:-

```
sudo systemctl enable rpcbind.service
sudo systemctl enable nfs-kernel-server
```

I can mount on a Ubuntu machine with:-

```
sudo mount -v -o noatime -t nfs 10.1.1.41:/home/pi ~/test
```

Unfortunately when I reboot Raspbian the `nfs-kernel-server.service` does not start.

```
systemctl status nfs-kernel-server.service
● nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-03-07 23:09:48 AEDT; 1 day 14h ago
  Process: 527 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

and I need to manually restart with:-

```
sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server.service
```

I have seen a few reports of similar problems by others, but none with solutions.

Comment: Did you look at `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/daemon.log` for messages regarding nfs/nfsd?

Comment: According to your output, the service *does* start and run successfully, exiting with "SUCCESS":

    Process: 527 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cleanup this old post.

The Jessie systemd service had a known bug, but this is now fixed.

The only thing you have to do under Stretch is `install nfs-kernel-server` - this now seems to have a proper systemd service, and `rpcbind` is now included by default.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem in Debian and not even specific to the Pi. The problem goes way back to the time when Debian changed from the `init` system to `systemd`.
The dependencies between nfs-kernel-server and rpcbind are not correctly defined. Debian/Raspbian still runs the old init.d scripts.
The simpliest way out for me was to insert a

```
start)
sleep 30   # this line is to be inserted!
export_files="/etc/export"
```

in `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server`. It was in line #63 on my system.
The hint came from https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/nfs-kernel-server-wont-start-on-boot/5936/7.
I had the problem on a Beagleboneblack and the sleep statement solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks, it explains `nfs-kernel-server[502]: Not starting: portmapper is not running `  however the sleep did not fix it.

Comment: perhaps you can have a look into the systemd units and can fix it? From what I read you seem to be a guy with the necessary knowledge and the time? ;-)